# generate date from datepicker

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker

I would like to understand the following code. Is there any way that I could select the date from the date picker and get the following weeks date instead of getting the real-time date? I tried to change  "var nextMonday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 1);" to var nextMonday = getNextWeekDay(new Date("#generate_date"), 1); but i could get it

```js
 function getNextWeekDay(startDate, dayOfWeek) {

    var dayOffset = dayOfWeek > startDate.getDay()
        ? dayOfWeek - startDate.getDay()
        : dayOfWeek - startDate.getDay() + 7;

    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + dayOffset);
  //alert("startDate>>"+startDate);

    return startDate;
}

var nextMonday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 1);
var nextTue = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 2);// 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ...
var nextwed = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 3);
var nextThur = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 4);
var nextFri = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 12);
var nextSaturday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 13);
var nextSunday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 14);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label"> Date</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="generate_date" id="generate_date" placeholder="Generate Date" >
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

```js
 function getNextWeekDay(startDate, dayOfWeek) {

    var dayOffset = dayOfWeek > startDate.getDay()
        ? dayOfWeek - startDate.getDay()
        : dayOfWeek - startDate.getDay() + 7;

    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + dayOffset);
  //alert("startDate>>"+startDate);

    return startDate;
}

var nextMonday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 1);
alert(nextMonday);
var nextTue = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 2);// 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ...
var nextwed = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 3);
var nextThur = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 4);
var nextFri = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 12);
var nextSaturday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 13);
var nextSunday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(), 14);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the `value` of any form element, not the element itself. So, the line you tried:

```
var nextMonday = getNextWeekDay(new Date("#generate_date"), 1)
```

refers to the date control's `id` as a string, but you need to actually refer to the date element as an object and then extract the `value` property from that. The line could be adjusted to:

```
// Get the object reference:
var datePicker = document.getElementById("#generate_date");

// Then use a property from the object:
var nextMonday = getNextWeekDay(new Date(datePicker.value), 1)
```

But, if I understand you correctly, you just want to get an offset date from the date selected in the date picker. That's just a matter of constructing a new Date that is offset from the original by an offset amount (7, I think you want).

```js
var datePicker = document.getElementById("generate_date"); // Get a reference to the date control

// Set up an event handler to run every time the value in the control is adjusted
datePicker.addEventListener("input", function(){
  // Call the function that gets the new date and pass it the current date
  // from the control and an amount of days to offset that date by
  getNextDate(new Date(this.value), 7);
});

function getNextDate(startDate, offset) {
    // Create a new Date that starts with the date in the control and is adjusted by the offset:
    alert("startDate>> " + 
      new Date(startDate.getYear(), startDate.getUTCMonth(), startDate.getUTCDate() + offset));
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label"> Date</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="generate_date" id="generate_date">
  </div>
</div>
```